# Getting: 'TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple', even though it is an int

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num_1 = 3
num_2 = 5
num_3 = 15
div_1 = 1000/3
div_2 = 1000/5
div_3 = 1000/15
sum_1 = 0
sum_2 = 0
sum_3 = 0
i = 0
while (i<300):
    sum_1 = sum_1 + i*3,
    i = i + 1
    print (sum_1)
i = 0
while (i<div_2):
    sum_2 = sum_2 + i*5,
    i += 1
i = 0
while (i<div_1):
    sum_3 = sum_3 + i*5,
    i += 1
print (sum_1)
```

Output:

```
(0,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Python/1-p.py", line 12, in <module
    sum_1 = sum_1 + i*3,
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

I am a beginner at Python and I am trying to write a simple code.

I am not sure what is going wrong. Can anyone please help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Try removing that comma from `i*3,`?

Comment: BTW, parentheses for `while` and other keywords are discouraged in Python unless they're necessary for clarity or to span multiple lines. `while i < 300:` is preferred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using commas where you shouldn't, creating tuples by accident:

```
sum_1 = sum_1 + i*3,  # < no comma needed there
```

Get rid of those commas and your code will work.

A comma creates a tuple in Python:

```
>>> 2,
(2,)
```

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks a lot! appreciate it! It works perfectly fine now.